# Removing content on the right of a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column that has data that stores paths and file names, like the following:

```
Quit_Smoking/Include_curriculum_and_learning_activities/ACTIVITY_Q_020214.pdf

Stay_SunSmart_every_day/Education_and_learning_activities/
ACTIVITY_S_Sid_Activity_Book_11213.pdf

Stay_SunSmart_every_day/Education_and_learning_activities/
ACTIVITY_S_SS_Colouring_Book_11213.pdf
```

We've since split the filename into a column of its own and need to remove it from this column. The trouble I'm having is that the filename length isn't all specific so the way I'd normally fix this (using `len()` and `right()`) won't work. How can i remove everything to the right of the last `/` in a column?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @S nvarchar(100) = 'Quit_Smoking/Include_curriculum_and_learning_activities/ACTIVITY_Q_020214.pdf'

select reverse(stuff(reverse(@S), 1, charindex('/', reverse(@S)), ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @S NVARCHAR(100) = 'Quit_Smoking/Include_curriculum_and_learning_activities/ACTIVITY_Q_020214.pdf';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@S, 1, LEN(@S) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@S)));
```